# Error installing rattle package in Mac

Tags: r, macos, rstudio

I am trying to install `rattle` package in `RStudio` on my Mac but I am getting the following error.

The error is **GTK version 2.8.0 required**. I tried to install `Gtk` via `Homebrew` but still the same problem.

What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: try `install.packages("rattle", dependencies=TRUE)`, If this does not work try installing all dependent packages separately.

Comment: Try installing the `RGtk2` package separately, and see if it gives you a more useful error message for why it's not installing.

Comment: http://rattle.togaware.com/rattle-install-troubleshooting.html

Comment: Thanks for responses, I tried them but still no use.

Comment: While this question is a long time ago, I would like to post [a note written by me](https://gist.github.com/zhiyzuo/a489ffdcc5da87f28f8589a55aa206dd) here in case someone's getting the same error/trouble on installing `rattle`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, since nothing worked, I uninstalled RStudio completely and also uninstalled R( also from Homebrew).

Then reinstalled everything again.

Here is what I did on another machine and it worked.

1. Install XQuartz from this [link](https://dl.bintray.com/xquartz/legacy-downloads/SL/XQuartz-2.7.8.dmg).
2. Install GTK+ from this [link](https://r.research.att.com/libs/GTK_2.24.17-X11.pkg).
3. run `install.packages("rattle", dependencies = T)`

This will work.

Comment: I got this machine problem too. My Mac  costs severals days to install while another computer just cost half an hour to install.

Answer (score 8):

There is no need for using `Rattle` of `fancyRpartPlot()` in order to get more sightful and readable graphs, we can easily load `rpart.plot` into our workspace which is hassle-free and usually comes with main `rpart` package. Just need to call it and pass the model as its parameter to draw a pretty plot from model

```
library(rpart.plot)
rpart.plot(model)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Update for macOS Sierra version 10.12.2

1. install.packages("ggplot2")
2. install.packages("magrittr")
3. install.packages("RGtk2")
4. install.packages("stringi")
5. install.packages("stringr")
6. install.packages("tidyr")
7. install.packages("dplyr")
8. download and install XQuartz from https://www.xquartz.org/
9. install.packages("rattle", repos="http://rattle.togaware.com",         type="source")
10. library(rattle)
11. rattle() #launch rattle

Answer (score 0):

If you have problem installing RGtk2, cairo is not probably installed either

After installing brew: run `brew link pcre`

try this to grant permissions if denied: `sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/local/man/man3/`

Install cairo: `brew install cairo`

Go to RStudio and run:

`install.packages("RGtk2")`, `install.packages("rattle")`